# Where do VS Code tunnels route my traffic

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using [Code CLI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_create-remote-tunnel) and [Remote - Tunnels](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels), is the entire connection to the VS Code Server (securely) routed through GitHub/Microsoft servers?

Where exactly does my network traffic go between originating in a Remote - Tunnels window of the VS Code desktop app, and terminating at a VS Code Server started by the Code CLI (and vice-versa)?

Do tunnels make sense when both are on localhost? Would this method introduce extra delay compared to [Remote - SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) or [Dev Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers)?

I read the [VS Code CLI documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_create-remote-tunnel) but was unable to find any concrete mentions of the network traffic routes.